# Uploading data source to server is deleting calc fields?

Tags: tableau-api

Have a data source being uploaded to a server environment. Calc fields I have are fine within my workbook before doing so, but sometimes the `=` portion of the name disappears and it turns into a regular dimensional field.

Example:

pre upload

[image]

post-upload

[image]

What could be causing that?

Comment: Have you tried to publish it under another name to see if issue is still there? Or delete current version on the server and republish.

Comment: IT isn't deleting the fields: it is including them in the datasource.